# How do Elesh Norn, Mother of Machines and Spark Double interact?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-planeswalkers

When [Spark Double](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spark%20Double) enters the battlefield and wants to copy a planeswalker, but the trigger triggers an additional time (e.g. because of [Elesh Norn, Mother of Machines](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elesh%20Norn%2C%20Mother%20of%20Machines)), does the first copy of a planeswalker leave loyalty counters for the second copy trigger of a planeswalker. Does it add up, the loyalty counters, in case of double trigger?

Comment: Isn't Spark Double's ability a *replacement* effect, rather than a triggered ability?

Comment: The link to the new Elesh Norn is broken at the moment since it's not in Gatherer yet. This is expected to be fixed shortly after the official release of its set. Meanwhile, enjoy [this link](https://scryfall.com/card/one/10/elesh-norn-mother-of-machines)

Answer (score 10):

**Spark Double's ability is not a triggered ability and so does not profit from Elesh Norn, Mother of Machines' ability.**

Spark Double's copying ability is not a triggered ability:

> 603.1. Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as “[When/Whenever/At] [trigger condition or event], [effect]. [Instructions (if any).]”

It is a static ability with a replacement effect:

> 614.1c Effects that read “[This permanent] enters the battlefield with . . . ,” “As [this permanent] enters the battlefield . . . ,” or “[This permanent] enters the battlefield as . . . “ are replacement effects.

As such, it does not benefit from "triggers another time" abilities.

Also, if several Spark Doubles copy the same planeswalker, even if they enter the battlefield at the same time, each copy will get the full amount of loyalty counters.